# Is it possible to assign a property value and return the original object?

Tags: dart

I want to avoid writing these three lines over and over in different functions.

```dart
var newState = state.copy();
newState.user.googleUser = googleUser;
state = newState;
```

Something like this?

```dart
state = (state.copy().user.googleUser = googleUser);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [cascade operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation):

```dart
state = state.copy()..user.googleUser = googleUser;
```

Alternatively, a common pattern is to instead create a `copyWith` method for your classes so that you can do:

```dart
state = state.copyWith(user: googleUser);
```

Comment: So operators (like =) are calculated from right to left? Ok thanks.